# use jquery to fade in button with hovering and the fadeout after hovering out

Tags: jquery

I need jquery to fade in a button when I hover over an image but then disappear after I hover off...I've been looking alot for this and I can't get it to disappear. Im using the hover() function and my button class is "goto" (#goto). Would I use a combination of fadein and fadeout?

Comment: please post the code what you have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/RBYVc/) what you want?

```
$("img").hover(
    function(){$(".goto").fadeIn()}
    ,function(){$(".goto").fadeOut()}
);
```

the jQuery `.hover()` can take 2 functions, the first being when hover on, the second when hover off http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: instead of goto wouldn't it be img in the selector ()?

Comment: You can use the "this" keyword inside the function to access the image. e.g $(this).fadeIn() or $(this).fadeOut()

Answer (score 0):

Well first off you say class goto and then say #goto, the # sign means its an id not a class. Assuming that you have something like this:

```
<div id=goto><img src="blah"></div>
```

Then your img is withing your div which you have made clickable. You then only need to fade in the overall div because the img is within the div.